# Getting logs of ssh access to pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud, and I'm trying to figure out a way to see all SSH access to the pods, whether it was done using the google cluster management tools, or via kubectl.

I want to be able to see which user account made the access, and ideally what commands they ran. I have stackdriver logging running on all instances which I think may already be recording these actions, but looking at the giant wall of logs, I can't figure out how to tell which of these were generated by someone sshing in.

Is there some kind of standard labeling schema in stackdriver to denote ssh access?

Comment: Perhaps it is pedantic, but one does not ssh into a Pod unless you have an ssh daemon running in the container, which I would strongly, strongly suggest against doing. Have you considered turning on [Auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) rather than trying to "reverse engineer" that information?

Comment: I may be using the incorrect terminology, but Google Cloud console does have a "connect" button that starts a session with the pod, and kubectl allows you to access bods through the terminal. I did look into auditing yesterday, and it is in fact on by default in Google Cloud. I was able to update my stackdriver filter to capture those logs, so I should close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that Google Cloud has Auditing enabled by default for Kubernetes, which logs many things, including access to the pod through kubectl. I was able to update my stackdriver log filter like so:

`protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"`

And get the logs I was interested in.